# where I can find kubeadm-config.yaml on my kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubeconfig

There is a k8s single master node, I need to back it up and restore it 
I googled this topic and found a solution - 
https://elastisys.com/2018/12/10/backup-kubernetes-how-and-why/

Everything looked easy; so,I followed the instruction and got a copy of the certificates and a snapshot of the etcd database.

But at last, I am not able to find  kubeadm-config.yaml on my master server.

Where to find this file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During kubeadm init, kubeadm uploads the ClusterConfiguration object to your cluster in a ConfigMap called kubeadm-config in the kube-system namespace. You can get it from the ConfigMap and take a backup

```
kubectl get cm kubeadm-config  -n kube-system -o yaml > kubeadm-config.yaml
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-config/

Comment: thanks, I got the kubeadm-config.yaml
but when I restore my master I got no no InitConfiguration or ClusterConfiguration kind was found in the YAML file

Comment: Initialize the master with backup
sudo kubeadm init --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--var-lib-etcd \
    --config /etc/kubeadm/kubeadm-config.yaml

Comment: share the yaml file in your question

Comment: this is the Configmap data which need to be reformatted into the actual config file before using it for kubeadm init

Comment: make sure to upload the latest updates : kubeadm config upload from-file